# Install and launch chrome in centos 7

Tags: centos7, google-chrome, graphical-user-interface

I am trying to standup google-chrome with gui in centos 7 which is from AWS EC2, i followed all the steps as given below still i didn't succeed, your help much appreciated.

1. Install chrome
2. yum install xorg-x11-server-Xvfb
3. start chrome - google-chrome --no-sandbox --disable-setuid-sandbox

I am getting the below error :

```
root@ip-10-125-152-150 centos]# google-chrome --no-sandbox --disable-setuid-sandbox
[3455:3455:1121/062948.445478:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(239)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY
[3455:3455:1121/062948.445524:ERROR:env.cc(255)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting.
[root@ip-10-125-152-150 centos]# [1121/062948.453798:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(354)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly
```

following is os details:

```
AME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with Gnome? Maybe works better.

https://cloudzy.com/blog/install-gui-on-centos-7/

Comment: If you have any GUI environment, making chrome ui working is easy. What i am looking for is to standup chrome ui without installing /having any desktop environment.